# Using wingIDE with a new module (not recognized)

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, wing-ide

Using my terminal, the code "**from PIL import Image**" works perfectly and is recognized by my computer. This allows me to get images using the path address.

**Here is my issue, when I open wingIDE and try the same code...this module isn't recognized.**

Is anyone familiar with wingIDE that can help me?
I would assume PyCharm people might have the same issue with possibly a similar fix, any advice??

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Wing is using a different Python than the one you installed Pillow into.  Try this on the command line:

import sys; sys.executable

Then set the Python Executable in Wing's Project Properties to the full path of that executable (or in Wing 101 this is set in the Configure Python dialog from the Edit menu).  You'll need to restart any debug process and/or the Python Shell from its Options menus.